# React; Keep focus in input when state change

Tags: reactjs, focus, use-state

I am writing an editor where I would like to be notified for any change into the
document. So I created a tree of components where each node report to the parent
via a `onChange(..)` callback:

```
// Pseudo structure.
Root {
    const [changed, setChanged] = useState(true)
    function onChange(..) {
      setChanged(true);
    }

    return (
        <App>
          <Status saved={!changed} />
          <Editor onChange={onChange}>
            <Text onChange={onChange} />
            <Image onChange={onChange} />
          </Editor>
        </App>
    );
}
```

Now I have to create a `<Table>` component where each cell is an editable input
that trigger the `onChange` callback. Because of the `useState` in `Root`, each
time we change one letter in the table, the whole structure is rendered.

But the rendering cause a loose of the focus, which is admittedly annoying to
type a text. My current solution is to save the current cell via `useMemo` in my
new `Table` component and request the focus when the component is rendered.
However, I still loose the caret position and I have the feeling this is a hacky
way of working (That's why I am reaching you).

How can I notify a change and update the state of my `Root` without losing the
focus from one input ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

1. Keep stateless components as child.
2. Use keys for each cell to avoid unnecessary rerendering from parent.

Comment: Okay.. I have the feeling that your first suggestion is already applied. I do not understand the second one; how can I avoid the `<Root>` to render while it is the parent of `<Status>` that should be re-rendered each time another child trigger a change ?